# Handle data from TextField

Tags: dart, flutter

1-i tried many times to retrieve the data from text filed in a good way like card or container but i cant access the list of controllers to view it inside 
and i don't wanna use json for the now 
i just want to retrieve what the user write in the fields
any help??

```
           import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

                class GUI extends StatefulWidget {
        @override
      _GUIState createState() => _GUIState();
 }



   class _GUIState extends State<GUI> {

//this is the TextControllers
  final fnController=TextEditingController();
  final lnController=TextEditingController();
  final cnController=TextEditingController();
  final mbController=TextEditingController();
  final agController=TextEditingController();
  final dnController=TextEditingController();
  final qidController=TextEditingController();

      List userInfo = 

 ['_fnController''_lnController''_cnController''_mbController''_agController''_dnController''_qidController'];
```

i tried to make the from in here

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MedForm'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
                child: Text(
              'Medical Registration Form ',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 22.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    controller: fnController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'First Name',
                      hintText: 'your First Name Please',
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: lnController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Last Name',
                      hintText: 'your Last Name Please',
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: cnController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Company Name',
                      hintText: 'your company Name Please',
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: mbController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Mobile Number',
                      hintText: 'your mobile Number Please',
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: agController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Age',
                      hintText: 'month \ day\ year',
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: dnController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'DR',
                      hintText: 'Specify Your Dr Please',
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: qidController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    maxLength: 11,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'QID',
                      hintText: 'your Qatari ID please',
                    ),
                  ),
```

i tried to make the view over card 
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Text('Submit'),
                        onPressed: () {
                           Card(
                             child: Text(fnController.text)
                           );

```
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
      ),
    );


  }
}
```

any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass text value of all `TextEditingController` as `List<String>` through `MaterialPageRoute`.

```
       FlatButton( child: Text('Submit'), onPressed: ()=> Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => NewPage([
                              fnController.text,
                              lnController.text,
                              cnController.text,
                              mbController.text,
                              agController.text,
                              dnController.text,
                              qidController.text
                            ])))),
                ]))
```

**Make a new page and create the initial constructor to receive data.**
Map the list of data in `ListView`.

```
class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  NewPage(this.list);
  List<String> list;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children:
          list.map((val) => Card(
            child: new ListTile(
              title: new Text(val),
            ),
          )).toList()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This will create List of all the value on next page. Hope this help!

Comment: i tried to make the output in the place of debug Print but nothing happened although the debug is printing the right value

Comment: For output in a widget create a function which returns Card if fnText contains text. If empty it'll return nothing. I've updated the answer.

Comment: lets do something 
we can't make a list of String and map it to a list of TextEditingController ??
because i have 8 text filed so why we didnt  pass the controller for the list of arguments and then we dont have to use onchanged or onsubmitted 
we will take the Argument.value.text and we pass it to the card 
how to do this ??

Comment: Can you state clearly what are you trying to achieve?
Do you want to display text of all textfields in a card?

Comment: the first code i mentioned that i have an input form i need the user to fill it then i want to take all the data from the filed and display it in a card or other page
so  i wanna fill the form then when i click on submit button 
i'll get the text in a card under the form or i'll navigate it later to other page

Comment: I have updated the code. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Order to Show the Value the `TextField` is having - Instead of using  `fnController.text` You need to Use - `fnController.value.text` **& so on..**

For you to Debug - i have Modified one `TextField` in your Code - As you Start entering the Text in the `TextField` you can See the *Value Print in Console*.

```
  final fnController = TextEditingController();
  String _name = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: TextField(
            controller: fnController,
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                _name = fnController.value.text;
              });
              debugPrint(fnController.value.text);
            },
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'First Name',
              hintText: 'your First Name Please',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Card(
          child: Text(_name),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Show text on Press of a Button:

```
final fnController = TextEditingController();
  String _name = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: TextField(
            controller: fnController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'First Name',
              hintText: 'your First Name Please',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _name = fnController.value.text;
            });
          },
          child: Text('Show Text'),
        ),
        Card(
          child: Text(_name),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

The Same thing Without using - `TextEditingController()`

```
String _name = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: TextField(
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                _name = val;
              });
            },
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'First Name',
              hintText: 'your First Name Please',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Card(
          child: Text(_name),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: yeah but how to display the value in a card under the form or on other page

Comment: Updated the Answer to Show the Value in the Card or in Any Other Widget You want.